# No response on if-elseif function

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a tool using macro so that when few criteria are selected, a certain rating will be shown. There are three criteria that need to be filtered before getting the result.

For example, if the industry (eg. `Agriculture`) is selected, followed by selection of countries (e.g `Indonesia`), followed by selection of certain ratio (e.g. `2.5`), a rating from 1 to 6 will be given (in this case, 3).

I tried the following code, nothing appears under my rating column but there is no error message. Is there anything missing in my code which causes no result happening?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Range("V4").Value = "A.Agriculture,forestry and fishing" Then

        If Range("W4").Value = All Or ID Or SG Then

            If Range("D4").Value <= 0 Then
                Range("X4").Value = 6
            ElseIf Range("M4").Value > 4 Then
                Range("X4").Value = 5
            ElseIf Range("M4").Value <= 4 And Value > 2 Then
                Range("X4").Value = 4
            ElseIf Range("M4").Value <= 2 And Value > 1 Then
                Range("X4").Value = 3
            ElseIf Range("M4").Value <= 1 And Value > 0 Then
                Range("X4").Value = 2
            ElseIf Range("M4").Value <= 0 Then
                Range("X4").Value = 1
            End If

        ElseIf Range("W4").Value = MY Or TH Then

            If Range("D4").Value <= 0 Then
                Range("X4").Value = 6
            ElseIf Range("M4").Value > 4.5 Then
                Range("X4").Value = 5
            ElseIf Range("M4").Value <= 4.5 And Value > 2 Then
                Range("X4").Value = 4
            ElseIf Range("M4").Value <= 2 And Value > 1 Then
                Range("X4").Value = 3
            ElseIf Range("M4").Value <= 1 And Value > 0 Then
                Range("X4").Value = 2
            ElseIf Range("M4").Value <= 0 Then
                Range("X4").Value = 1
            End If

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it at all? Set breakpoints where you expect things to be called. (Excel can do that, right? If not, `Debug.Print` or `MsgBox` should work.)

Comment: @RyanO'Hara F9 sets a breakpoint in the VBE, regardless of the host application ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured it out. I am also trying to replicate the entire macro on inputs in other rows, not just on row4, anyone has suggestion?

Comment: @Ryan O'Hara, Would you mind telling me why my question is put on hold? I can't seem to figure out the problem. My question looks just fine.

Comment: @tnkh: The accepted answer is just general debugging advice. If you found the problem through that and it’s in your question, just say so and you can post a self-answer with details. If the problem is in code that’s *not* in your question, that code is going to have to be included for the question to be answerable/useful to other people. Also, if you have another question, you should ask another question; nobody will see it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your If statements with **Or** are not properly formed. Additionally, a combination of **If** and [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx)s would seem to be best for these multiple, nested conditions. This should also make your code mode readable.

```
If Range("W4").Value = "All" Or Range("W4").Value = "ID" Or Range("W4").Value = "SG" Then
```

VBA is case sensitive by default and strings need to be enclosed in quotes; e.g. `All <> "All"` and `"ALL" <> "all"`. Best to use the [LCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264497.aspx) and [UCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264252.aspx) functions to compare `"Apples"` with `"Apples"`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Range("V4").Value = "A.Agriculture,forestry and fishing" Then
        Select Case LCase(Range("W4").Value)
            Case "all", "id", "sg"
                If Range("D4").Value <= 0 Then
                    Range("X4").Value = 6
                Else
                    Select Case Range("M4").Value
                        Case Is > 4
                            Range("X4").Value = 5
                        Case 2.01 To 4
                            Range("X4").Value = 4
                        Case 1.01 To 2
                            Range("X4").Value = 3
                        Case 0.01 To 1
                            Range("X4").Value = 2
                        Case Is <= 0
                            Range("X4").Value = 1
                        Case Is > 4
                            Range("X4").Value = 6
                    End Select
                End If
            Case "my", "th"
                If Range("D4").Value <= 0 Then
                    Range("X4").Value = 6
                Else
                    Select Case Range("M4").Value
                        Case Is > 4.5
                            Range("X4").Value = 5
                        Case 2.01 To 4.5
                            Range("X4").Value = 4
                        Case 1.01 To 2
                            Range("X4").Value = 3
                        Case 0.01 To 1
                            Range("X4").Value = 2
                        Case Is <= 0
                            Range("X4").Value = 1
                        Case Is > 4
                            Range("X4").Value = 6
                    End Select
                End If
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Note that I have added a small decimal value to the **between** style Case statements in order to achieve the *greater than and less than or equal to* logic.

Comment: thanks a lot. Your codes look much more cleaner. I am also trying to replicate the result on every single row, not just on row 4, but don't know how. Could you help me out on this?

Comment: That would seem to be a different question and changes to a question that invalidate the original answer(s) are discouraged. (see [Russian Doll Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625)) Close this off and start another question with less code that shows your own attempt at looping through the rows if you run into trouble. There are hundreds of examples on this site.

Comment: Say for example if for `"my" or th"` case where the value for `Range("M4")` is 2.005, would `range("X4") `shows a 3 or 4?

Comment: It would show a **3**. If you wanted a **4** increase the small decimal I added to each to avoid the problem of **>** and **<=**. e.g. `Case 2.0001 To 4.5`

Answer (score 1):

Add an `Else` case at the very end to handle errors. Chances are your `If... ElseIf` block isn't actually doing anything.

Also,  because you are checking so many **CASES**, this looks like a great opportunity to re-structure your `If... Then` block to a `Select... Case` block..

```
Select [ Case ] testexpression 'stuff here

[ Case expression1 ]

    [ statements ] ]

[ Case Else
    [ elsestatements ] ]
End Select
```

more info - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx for info.

Comment: Thank you @The Zombro. Using your suggestion, I managed to find out what's wrong with my codes.

Comment: such downvotes... why??? :(

Comment: I think it should someone did it. Definitely not me. Cheers.